Cannot convert value of type String to required type PersonDTO for property 'person'
I have a class named Tabel that has an person. The classes Tabel and Person have a one-to-many relationship.
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "tabel")
public class Tabel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String comments;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private Person person;

}

@Entity
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String lastname;
    private String surname;

}

There are also DTOs
@Data
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Jacksonized
public class TabelDto implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String comments;
    private PersonDto person;
}

@Value
@Builder
public class PersonDto implements Serializable {
    Long id;
    String name;
    String lastname;
    String surname;
}

And my controller
@PostMapping("/addTabel")
public String addTabel(@ModelAttribute TabelDto tabelDto) {
    tabelService.save(tabelDto);
    return "redirect:/addTabel";
}

@GetMapping("/addTabel")
public String addTabel(Model model) {
    TabelDto tabelDto = TabelDto.builder().build();
    model.addAttribute("persons", personService.findAllPerson());
    model.addAttribute("tabelDTO", tabelDto);
    return "addTabel";
}

My HTML Thymeleaf
<form action="#" th:action="@{/tabel/addTabel}" method="post" th:object="${tabelDTO}">
    <label>person:</label>
    <label>
        <select th:field="*{person}" class="form-control">
            <option th:each="person: ${persons}" th:value="${person.id}" th:text="${person.name}"></option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>

When I try to send a POST, I get an error.
[tabel] [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [0] in public java.lang.String by.gus.tabel.controller.TabelController.addTabel(by.gus.tabel.dto.TabelDto): [Field error in object 'tabelDto' on field 'person': rejected value [1]; codes [typeMismatch.tabelDto.person,typeMismatch.person,typeMismatch.by.gus.tabel.dto.PersonDto,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [tabelDto.person,person]; arguments []; default message [person]]; default message [Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'by.gus.tabel.dto.PersonDto'; Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'by.gus.tabel.dto.PersonDto' for property 'person': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]] ]

But if you put the Table class instead of the TableDTO
public String addTabel(@ModelAttribute Tabel tabelDto)

then everything starts working, but I would like to work through the DTO, and not directly with the entity.
How can I solve this?

Can you please share your service methods declarations too?
It seems like the request should be accepted at least at controller level, if I am not wrong.
Or you might be passing string for value of the key person. It should be JSON.

@SatyaRajAwasthi  Method save  public TabelDto save(TabelDto tabelDto) {         System.out.println(tabelDto);         return tableMapper.toTabelDto(tabelRepository.save(tableMapper.toTabel(tabelDto)));     } but it doesn't reach the controller

What is the value of type String which is sent to the property person?

@RomanC value "1" - person.id

What is the name of parameter passing this value?

What I see wrong here is you are adding tabel and you do have PersonDto as person within tabel. But, you are passing value of person id selected upon selecting the name of person from options.
If you are just trying to pass person.Id as value for person you can make the variable Long or numeric. Else, you can add everything.
    @Data
    @Builder
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    @Jacksonized
    public class TabelDto implements Serializable {
        private Long id;
        private String comments;
        private Long personId; // Change from PersonDto to Long
    }


<form action="#" th:action="@{/tabel/addTabel}" method="post" th:object="${tabelDTO}">
    <label>person:</label>
    <label>
        <select th:field="*{personId}" class="form-control">
            <option th:each="person: ${persons}" th:value="${person.id}" th:text="${person.name}"></option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>

OR
<form action="#" th:action="@{/tabel/addTabel}" method="post" th:object="${tabelDTO}">
    <label>Comments:</label>
    <textarea th:field="*{comments}" class="form-control"></textarea>

    <label>Person Name:</label>
    <input th:field="*{person.name}" class="form-control" />

    <label>Person Lastname:</label>
    <input th:field="*{person.lastname}" class="form-control" />

    <label>Person Surname:</label>
    <input th:field="*{person.surname}" class="form-control" />

    <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>

